# dcc.Upload to create dcc.graph, but how is placeholder dcc.graph already in layout updated?

Tags: plotly-dash

I'm using dcc.Upload to read data from a spreadsheet.  That data is manipulated, put into a pandas data frame, and then px.line is created.  I wish to pass px.line to a dcc.Graph in my layout.  The graph can be displayed with .show() but not in the dcc.Graph created in my layout.

Intuitively, I simply want to update dcc.Graph in my layout, but that doesn't seem possible without a callback.  I can return px.line to the function associated with dcc.Upload, but I can't get it from there to the dcc.Graph I wish to update.  Adding a second output to dcc.Upload to update dcc.Graph in my layout doesn't work.

Essentially, I'm trying to update a graph by pointing to a spreadsheet with dcc.Upload.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks, little_old_man

As mentioned, I tried adding a second output to the dcc.Upload callback to update dcc.Graph in my layout, but that led to an error.

I've looked at dcc.Interval to poll for some signal to update the graph independent of any user input.  Pointing to the spreadsheet in dcc.Upload is the user input.

I'm still stuck moving the data created from the input spreadsheet outside the scope of dcc.Upload to the dcc.Graph in my  layout.  Is dcc.Store needed?

Comment: Can you share your app.layout with us?

Comment: Hope it's ok to paste entire program here.

Comment: It wasn't.  Here's just the layout.

Comment: That was too long too.

Comment: I've tried a few more experiments since original post.  My code is based on the Upload component (https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/upload).  I'm using parse_contents to create a figure that I want to return with the other items returned.  However, I want to return the figure to a different part of the layout than that associated with the Upload component in the layout.  Here's the error received: Callback error updating ..output-data-upload.children...impulse_response_fig.figure...  Thanks, little_old_man

Comment: Can you share the app layout with us? That is essential (for me at least) to be able to help.

Comment: Here's the layout.

Comment: I no longer wish to pursue this.